# listagg to rows in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I need to transform a list to rows to be added later, the list comes from rows in a grouped select

```
select
    retail ,
    listagg( distinct trn.header_id::varchar||'_'||trn.total_sale::varchar,',') as "total_sale"
from 
    ventas.mw_mdh_transactions trn
group by 
    retail
```

I need to read the list and add it up in the same query. All this in REDSHIFT.

for example this ...

```
select
    retail ,
    select z from unnest(listagg( distinct trn.header_id::varchar||'_'||trn.total_sale::varchar,',')) z as "total_sale"
from 
    ventas.mw_mdh_transactions trn
group by 
    retail
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Please add some sample data with expected output.

Comment: What is the rule to apply to that list and turn it to the output's structure?

Comment: I need to make an unnest to that listagg or other option that they recommend me ... ?

Comment: I was able to solve it, no one has done it before